# .Net Sending SMTP Mail from dev machine (not server) utilizing hmailserver

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient, mail-server, hmail-server

I've been trying to figure out how to make my smtp mail to work. I have my dev environment set up on my computer, it currently uses Windows 7 home premium. Whenever I'm done doing changes I'd publish it to my host. Now I have a few site functionality that requires sending emails. When the site is published it works fine, but when on my localhost it would always fail. I've been reading a few forum posts and SO questions and it seems to me that I have to install a smtp application? I have picked hMailServer as it's the most common one I see. My problem is though I'm not sure if I have set it up correctly. When I build and run my site, it would still throw the same error (Failure sending mail).

This is my code:

```
try
{
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMTP = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(); 
                    SMTP.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@mydomainexample.com", "ghandi");
                    SMTP.Host = "mail.mydomainexample.com";
                    SMTP.Port = 25;

    SMTP.Send(Email);

            }catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                throw new SmtpException("SMTP Exception. " + smtpEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error on Sending Mail. " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Can anybody point me to the right direction as to how I can make sure the smtp application is working.

NOTE: I've followed the following link in configuring my hMailServer installation:

http://support.moonpoint.com/network/email/hmailserver/

However, I am stuck in this area:

> "When you set the value for the local host name, if you telnet to port
>   25 on the server, you will see it listed in the banner returned by the
>   server."